# Count Projects in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I use Visual Studio 2015 and Team Foundation Server 2017.

I wonder if there's a solution to know:

- How many projects are currently there in TFS?
- Where can I find these information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with PowerShell, by enumerating through all Collections. [Here is an example.](http://blog.majcica.com/2015/11/15/powershell-tips-and-tricks-retrieving-tfs-collections-and-projects/)